# Spring Elasticsearch Template Custom Fields Name

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using Spring-Data-Elasticsearch to query my elasticsearch server.

Here is my data and code:

#### Elasticsearch :

```
{
  "user" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "user" : {
        "properties" : {
          "id" : { "type" : "long" },
          "first_name" : { "type" : "string" },
          "last_name" : { "type" : "string" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Java Model :

```
@Document(indexName = "user", type = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @JsonProperty("last_name")
    private String lastName;
}
```

#### Java Repository :

```
public class UserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<User, Long> {

    List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName);

    List<User> findByLastName(String LastName);
}
```

#### Java Test Case :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations="classpath:dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class ElasticsearchTest {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        User user1 = repository.findOne(1L);
        System.out.println(user1);

        List<User> users1 = repository.findByFirstName("Jack");
        System.out.println(users1);

        List<User> users2 = repository.findByLastName("Lin");
        System.out.println(users2);
    }
}
```

#### Output :

user1:

```
User(id=1, firstName=Jack, lastName=Lin)
```

users1:

```
[]
```

users2:

```
[]
```

and Elasticsearch Template DEBUG info :

```
12:33:13,381 DEBUG ElasticsearchTemplate [main]:325 - doSearch query:
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 1,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "Jack",
          "fields" : [ "firstName" ],
          "default_operator" : "and"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

12:33:13,392 DEBUG ElasticsearchTemplate [main]:325 - doSearch query:
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 1,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "Lin",
          "fields" : [ "lastName" ],
          "default_operator" : "and"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but in my elasticsearch, the field name is `first_name` and `last_name`, i use `@JsonProperty` in my model, but it's not work in ElasticsearchTemplate.

Why ... ?

Comment: I know it's work with

    @Query("{\"bool\" : {\"must\" : {\"match\" : {\"first_name\" : \"?\"}}}}")
    List<User> findByFirstName(String firstName);

Comment: but i don't want to write these query string

Comment: What is the debug of the operational query?

Comment: I want to the 『query_string』is 『"fields" : ["first_name"]』, not 『"fields" : ["firstName"]』

Comment: Right, I understand what you are looking for. What I am asking is this: you have three queries, but only show two debug output statements. I'm asking to see the third output statement, which likely shows the same query that you are writing by hand but I'm looking to validate that. 

The reason is this: if findOne is working right, then likely the @JsonProperty is OK, but until there's a debug statement, we can't be sure.

BTW: I learned from experience to not use underscores in my mapping fields in ElasticSearch fir just this reason - it's a pain to debug.